# ST3 SublimeLinter with HTML tidy doesn't obey args

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimelinter

I want to suppress various kind of useless linter error reports, e.g.  lacks "content" attribute. So I tried experimenting with setting the options in SublimeLinter.sublime-settings:

```
    "linters": {
        "htmltidy": {
            "@disable": false,
            "args": [-xxx true],
            "excludes": []
        }
    },
```

and so on and they don't seem to do anything. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings file is a JSON file, and it looks like your edits are not valid JSON. Try putting quotes around the args, either:

```
"args": ["-xxx true"]
```

or

```
"args": ["-xxx", "true"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
"linters": {
    "htmltidy": {
        "@disable": false,
        "args": [
            //http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html
            "--drop-proprietary-attributes", "false"
        ],
        "excludes": []
    }...
```

Comment: It might be valid JSON and not throwing an error, but it's not actually applying drop proprietary attributes, try enabling the debug mode in the SublimeLinter.sublime-settings